# I have two datamodel and I want to display it in the same datatable

Tags: java, database, jsf

This is the datamodel of critere

```
private DataModel<Criteres> dataModel = new ListDataModel<Criteres>();
private DataModel<Appreciation>dataModelA = new ListDataModel<Appreciation>();

public DataModel<Criteres> getDataModel() {
    dataModel.setWrappedData(criteresservice.findid());
    return dataModel;
}
    //setter//
```

This is datamodel of appreciation

```
public DataModel<Appreciation> getDataModelA() {
    dataModelA.setWrappedData(appreciationservice.listAllAppreciation());
    return dataModelA;
}
    //setter//
```

Is there a solution to display it in the same datatable in my xhtml page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. Data table is used to display data from objects of the same type. If `Criteres` and `Appreciation` has nothing to do with each other, there's no way to do that.

However, if there's a relationship between `Criteres` and `Appreciation`, you can create a custom class (type) of object and declare that relationship there. For example, if each `Appreciation` object is like a `+1 like` for one `Criteres` object, you can create the following class:

```
public class CustomCriteres {
    private Criteres criteres;
    private List<Appreciation> appreciations; // 2 appreciations ~ 2 likes, n appreciations ~ n likes

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Then in the backing bean for your data table, you can have a `DataModel` of `CustomCriteres` objects. It'd be something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MrBean {
    private DataModel<CustomCriteres> customModel;

    public DataModel<CustomCriteres> getCustomModel() {
        /* This is where you would get both `Criteres` and ALL of the related 
          `Appreciation` objects at the same time and put them in 1 single 
           instance of `CustomCriteres` object */ 
    }
}
```

At this point, you can already use the `customModel` for your data table.